# Are there greenDAO thread safety best practices?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, greendao

I'm having a go with [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) and so far it's going pretty well.  One thing that doesn't seem to be covered by the docs or website (or anywhere :( ) is how it handles thread safety.

I know the basics mentioned elsewhere, like "use a single dao session" (general practice for Android + SQLite), and I understand the Java memory model quite well.  The library internals even appear threadsafe, or at least built with that intention.  But nothing I've seen covers this:

**greenDAO caches entities by default.**  This is excellent for a completely single-threaded program - transparent and a massive performance boost for most uses.  But if I e.g. `loadAll()` and then modify one of the elements, I'm modifying the same object *globally* across my app.  If I'm using it on the main thread (e.g. for display), and updating the DB on a background thread (as is right and proper), there are obvious threading problems unless extra care is taken.

Does greenDAO do anything "under the hood" to protect against common application-level threading problems?  For example, modifying a cached entity in the UI thread while saving it in a background thread (better hope they don't interleave! especially when modifying a list!)?  Are there any "best practices" to protect against them, beyond general thread safety concerns (i.e. something that greenDAO expects and works well with)?  Or is the whole cache fatally flawed from a multithreaded-application safety standpoint?

Answer (score 2):

I've no experience with greenDAO but the documentation here:
http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/

Says:

> If you use queries in multiple threads, you must call forCurrentThread() on the query to get a Query instance for the current thread. Starting with greenDAO 1.3, object instances of Query are bound to their owning thread that build the query. This lets you safely set parameters on the Query object while other threads cannot interfere. If other threads try to set parameters on the query or execute the query bound to another thread, an exception will be thrown. Like this, you don’t need a synchronized statement. In fact you should avoid locking because this may lead to deadlocks if concurrent transactions use the same Query object.
>
> To avoid those potential deadlocks completely, greenDAO 1.3 introduced the method forCurrentThread(). This will return a thread-local instance of the Query, which is safe to use in the current thread. Every time, forCurrentThread() is called, the parameters are set to the initial parameters at the time the query was built using its builder.

While so far as I can see the documentation doesn't explicitly say anything about multi threading other than this this seems pretty clear that it is handled. This is talking about multiple threads using the same Query object, so clearly multiple threads can access the same database. Certainly it's normal for databases and DAO to handle concurrent access and there are a lot of proven techniques for working with caches in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

By default GreenDAO caches and returns cached entity instances to improve performance. To prevent this behaviour, you need to call:

`daoSession.clear()`

to clear all cached instances. Alternatively you can call:

`objectDao.detachAll()`

to clear cached instances only for the specific DAO object.

You will need to call these methods every time you want to clear the cached instances, so if you want to disable all caching, I recommend calling them in your Session or DAO accessor methods.

- Documentation:
  http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/sessions/#Clear_the_identity_scope
- Discussion: https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/776